# Using UIScrollview in iphone5 compatible app

Tags: ios, layout, uiscrollview, keyboard, ios6

I have a problem adapting my apps to the new iphone5 layout, I've made the following passes:

1. Added a retina 4" splash image
2. Modified the interface in my storyboard with "Size inspector" to change the anchoring of the widgets
3. Tested the app with iOS6 "retina 4" simulator.

The app works as expected except when the user pop up the keyboard to edit a text, I use the "stretching scrollview" method for this particular situation and this seems not compatibile with the "autosizing" properties of my widgets, here is an example, from iOS6 simulator, without and with keyboard:

[image: Interface with a middle item that is not anchored to fill the iphone5 screen]

And here is what happens:

[image: The mess that happens once the keyboard is shown]

I'm quite sure this is a coherent behaviour since my main view is stretched so the other items inside it are stretched following their anchoring, the fact is that I'd like to have the same behaviour of my previous fixed position (all widgets anchored to the top left corner) with the iphone5 gui expansion, is this possibile?

How do you solve the problem of showing a keyboard and scroll hidden content in an iphone 5 compatible way?

Comment: The code I use to resize the scrollview on keyboard appear/disappear is the one suggested by apple [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH5-SW7)

Answer (score 0):

I have been having similar problems.  From what I have found thus far, we may need to remove all constraints on the view within the scrollable view, because it appears that it's contents are being resized along with the frame of the scrollView.  I know that setting the internal view's frame manually in viewWillAppear will work, but then you are stuck having a view that is the same size for both iPhone4 and iPhone5 (albeit it will scroll).  Or you could "pin height and pin width" of the internalView right there in storyboard.

Two potential approaches that may work. Sorry I can't confirm these as I'm giving up and redesigning around this problem.
1. Programmatically add constraints to your internal view's subviews.  The programmatic constraints will allow you to "spring" the distance between your elements proportionally.  When adding constraints programmatically, you are given access to a factor called "multiplier" (not to be confused with priority), which I saw someone else on stackoverflow posting about. 
2. You can design the internalView in Interface Builder as a separate viewController with it's .xib file, and then use storyboard to load it as an embedded viewController to a "containerView" object, which you would put in place as the new "internal view" of the scrollView.  Perhaps then the .xib would first resize to the correct iOS device, and then you could use its frame to resize the containerView.

My advice is create a small test-case of these before implementing, else you end up like me, having spent hours down the wrong path and facing a dead-end.

UPDATE 12/4/12
Make your life easier by NOT setting the ScrollView as the main view of the ViewController.
--Instead, make ViewController.view a dummy/blank view, and embed a scrollView inside that view.  Then, embed another view (my CustomView) in the ScrollView.  CustomView contains all the visible controls and text boxes and buttons.  There is NO HEIGHT CONSTRAINT on CustomView.